# Why does SQL query return no results?

Tags: c#, database, sql-server-ce, sql-delete

I am using a SQL Server Compact database to store sensor data gathered via serial port, in a C# application. I use the following query to retrieve data and it works fine:

```
public List<Record> GetData(DateTime startDatetime, DateTime endDatetime, string sensor)
{
        dataTable = new DataTable();

        using (connection = new SqlCeConnection(connectionString))
        {
            connection.Open();
            dataAdapter = new SqlCeDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM data WHERE sensor = @sensor AND dt BETWEEN @startDatetime AND @endDatetime", connection);
            dataAdapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@startDatetime", startDatetime);
            dataAdapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@endDatetime", endDatetime);
            dataAdapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sensor", sensor);

            dataAdapter.Fill(dataTable);
            connection.Close();
        }

        List<Record> records = new List<Record>();

        foreach (DataRow row in dataTable.Rows)
        {
            records.Add(new Record
            {
                Id = (int)row["Id"],
                dt = (DateTime)row["dt"],
                sensor = row["sensor"].ToString(),
                port = (int)row["port"],
                measuredValue = row["measuredValue"].ToString(),
                value = (double)row["value"],
                unit = row["unit"].ToString()
            });
        }

        return records;
}
```

The problem is that if I delete all records in the database *and wait for the database to be populated with a few records*, the query returns no results!

This is the delete query:

```
public void DeleteAllData()
{
        using (connection = new SqlCeConnection(connectionString))
        {
            connection.Open();

            using (SqlCeCommand command = new SqlCeCommand("DELETE FROM data", connection))
            {
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }

            connection.Close();
        }
}
```

It works only if I restart the application.

Does anybody know why I cannot retrieve any records after using the delete query? I confirm that the database does contain records.

Comment: `startDatetime` & `endDatetime` filters the result - do you change them after delete query, or do they changed only after app restart?

Comment: I reckon that the date/times you are supplying are not updated before calling the query.

Comment: You may have issue with both functions using the same connection and running simultaneously.  It is possible you are getting an exception that is not being reported..

Comment: @Lanorkin Thanks for observing that. Indeed, the two datetimes were the same and all records after DB deletion had datetimes higher than the endDatetime. It is solved now. Thank you again! You can post this suggestion so I can mark it as an answer.

Comment: @CristianM I'm glad to hear it helped, but I don't think this is actually valuable answer for the community; I vote for offtopic as this one "was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers."